# How to compare a non-random sample with known population?

Tags: self-study, stata

I'm currently working on my first substantial data project and I'm using stata (though I could probably just as well be using excel).  The project deals with lobbying data and unfortunately I haven't got much background information on the lobbyists beyond what's already in the data (past government experience), so I can't really go trying to build a model or anything; at this point I'm resigned to examining a sample of lobbyists no longer registered to see if there are differences compared to their peers.  The variables at hand are mostly measures of activity like income, number of issues covered, etc., while the observations are lobbyist-years.  Given that the sample is non-random and that I know the population parameters, it seems my tools are limited to descriptive stats.  Any ideas on how I might go about illustrating the differences beyond comparing, for example, means between the sample and population?  I feel like I'm missing something...